# Archivo Excel - Columna con formato texto (C#)

Tags: c#

Buen día,

Estoy creando un archivo Excel y una de las columnas contiene números. En la aplicación lo trato siempre como texto pero al mandarlo a Excel lo transforma en formato numérico, el problema es que cuando el número comienza con 0 me lo quita cuando lo exporto, y necesito que me traiga el 0.

¿Cómo podría cambiar el formato de esta columna para que se visualice como texto?

```
private void btnImp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Grid.Rows.Count > -1)
        {


            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);
            int IndiceColumna = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in Grid.Columns) // Columnas - agrega todas las columnas al documento de Excel
            {

                IndiceColumna++;

                excel.Cells[1, IndiceColumna] = col.Name;

            }

            int IndeceFila = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Grid.Rows) // Filas - Agrega todas las filas al documento de Excel
            {

                IndeceFila++;

                IndiceColumna = 0;

                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in Grid.Columns)
                {

                    IndiceColumna++;

                    excel.Cells[IndeceFila + 1, IndiceColumna] = row.Cells[col.Name].Value;

                }

            }

            excel.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

Atentamente,
Cristhian Pérez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo concatena una comilla simple antes de asignar el valor a la celda.

Ejemplo:

```
excelWorkSheet.Cells[indexRow, indexColumn] = "'" + value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Si yo asumiera que no se nada de programación, que solo soy un usuario con algunas habilidades en el uso de Excel te diría que para evitar que eso ocurra en Excel, a la celda hay que definir el formato de celda como formato de Texto, si le colocas un valor sin especificar formato, el Excel tomara de manera automática el formato que más se acerque según criterios establecidos por sus desarrolladores al valor que estas introduciendo, un valor "0012568" lo más cercano le parecería un número igual a 12568, pues los ceros a la izquierda nada significan y por tanto le asignaría un formato numérico y no mostraría ceros a la izquierda.
Si deseas que los ceros a la izquierda, se muestren, habrá que especificar que el formato de la celda es formato de Texto.
Todo lo anterior nada tiene que ver con programación, ni siquiera con programación con Visual Basic para aplicaciones, todo es solo conocimientos básicos del uso de Excel, en Excel a cada celda le debes especificar su formato, que puede ser de múltiples formas.
Tu problema solo radica en saber como colocarle a la celda que debe almacenar el valor, cual es su formato adecuado, si deseas que los ceros a la izquierda aparezcan debes especificar formato de Texto para la celda, te coloco a continuación la forma de establecer varios formatos para las celdas en Excel, ten en cuenta que en mi ejemplo cld es una celda de un tipo de dato Tabla creado por mi y CrClda es la celda de Excel.

```
  if (cld.TipoDato == Controles_Captura.Tipo_Dato.Decimal)
  {
     //Para decimales con separador de miles y 4 lugares después del separador decimal. 
     CrClda.Value2 = System.Convert.ToDouble(cld.Valor);
     CrClda.NumberFormat = "#"+NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberGroupSeparator+"##0" + NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator + "0000";
  }
  else if (cld.TipoDato == Controles_Captura.Tipo_Dato.Entero)
  {
    //Para enteros. 
     CrClda.Value2 = System.Convert.ToDouble(cld.Valor);
     CrClda.NumberFormat = "#" + NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberGroupSeparator + "##0";
  }
  else
 {
    //Para texto, en este caso mostraría los ceros a la izquierda.
    CrClda.Value2 = cld.Valor.ToString();
    CrClda.NumberFormat = "@";
 }
```

En tiempo de diseño en programación, se trata solo de establecer de manera adecuada la propiedad `NumberFormat` de la celda de Excel.
Este fragmento de código, es parte de un software que ya he desarrollado y que funciona perfectamente.
En tu código la linea adecuada seria lo siguiente:

```
excel.Cells[IndeceFila + 1, IndiceColumna].Value2 = row.Cells[col.Name].Value;
excel.Cells[IndeceFila + 1, IndiceColumna].NumberFormat = "@";
```

Solo así de simple.

Comment: @CristhianAndrésPérezSánchez Coloque una respuesta a tu problema, creo que hayas sido tu quien otorgó un voto positivo a mi respuesta, si es así me gustaría conocer tu criterio en un comentario y además si lo consideras justo que marcaras mi repuesta como aceptada, soy nuevo en este sitio y además desarrollador autodidacta  y me seria de mucho estimulo recibir esa votación.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, realmente me sirvió mucho para el problema que tenia.

Comment: @CristhianAndrésPérezSánchez Complacido y estimulado que mi respuesta te haya resultado de mucha ayuda, estamos en este sitio para colaborar, muchas gracias por elegir mi respuesta como correcta y por tu puntuación. Gracias además para cualquier otro que haya punteado mi respuesta.

Comment: @CristhianAndrésPérezSánchez He editado mi respuesta pues es claro que había un error en ella, el orden de las lineas no es critico en mi ejemplo, puedes asignar valor y luego cambiar formato de celda o a la inversa, solo que mi primera linea debe quedar como ahora la coloqué; ´excel.Cells[IndeceFila + 1, IndiceColumna].Value2= row.Cells[col.Name].Value´ ya que lo que estamos asignando valor a la celda.

Comment: @CristhianAndrésPérezSánchez. En el primer bloque de código de mi repuesta, todo está correcto.